# Annoyance - How to disable Eclipse classpath entry warnings

Tags: java, eclipse

I've searched the options but I can't seem to find a way to disable these warnings. Warnings such as this:

```
Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4 will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.
```

Simply serve no purpose to me on my project other than to clutter my "Problems" view.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[bug 190783](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=190783) might be relevant to this question.

> this warning will now have two Quick Fixes:
>
> -one that adds the "`dependency`" attribute (this is the current quick fix)
>
> -one that adds the "`nondependency`" attribute; the addition of this attribute will explicitly exclude the cp entry from consideration as a potential publish/export dependency. If the user changes their mind, they can remove this attribute via the JDT build path UI.

As [Mondain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127938/mondain) comments:

> I found it! Right click on the warning and select quick fix, yay!

That is indeed how you can use Quick Fix: See also [FAQ What is a Quick Fix?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_Quick_Fix%3F), [Quick Fix](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-quickfix.htm), and [Quick Assist](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-quickfix-assist.htm)

[image]

Comment: Nice find! I'm surprised that its not fixed yet after 6 releases (3.0 -> 3.6).

Comment: The quick fix is there in 3.6.  It solved the problem for me.

Comment: Ok maybe I'm playing dumb here, but where do I set the attribute? Do I need to text-edit the .classpath file?

Comment: @Mondain: I don't have the right Eclipse edition at hand right now, but if Skip reports the quick fixes are available in 3.6, those quick fixes will add the attributes for you in the right places.

Comment: I found it! Right click on the warning and select quick fix, yay!

Comment: @Mondain: great! I have update the answer with links and picture describing how to use "quick fix" for future readers.

Comment: Awesome that we found the answer, but extremely frustrating that you have to do this for each and every individual JAR. There's no way to mark all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for a whole project (may be too greedy though).  Assumes linux utilities (or cygwin):

```
cp .classpath classpath-bak
cat classpath-bak | sed 's@^\(\s*<classpathentry kind=.*\)/>\s*$@\1><attributes><attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/></attributes></classpathentry>@' > .classpath
```