# Why am I receiving this 404 Error in my Maven Dynamic Web Module?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm brand-new to Jersey/JAX-RS/RESTful Web Services/etc. and I'm having difficulty with a Jersey archetype called `jersey-quickstart-webapp`. I'm attempting to use it with Eclipse, Maven, and Tomcat v7 or v8 (I've tried both).

First I got a JSP error:
    `The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path.`
  I resolved that error with [this SO question regarding the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25266076/2877415). Apparently Maven wasn't treating my project as a Dynamic Web Application.

Then I got a warning about:
`Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment`. I resolved the second issue with [another SO question on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805111/2877415). I was originally using JavaSE-1.8.

Finally, I had one last error:
`Classpath entry org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.`Again, I checked SO on the matter and [excluded the associated raw classpath entry from the set of potential publish/export dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455576/2877415).

However, I am still given a 404 on my project and I cannot figure out why. I'm using a pom.xml file for this project. The [tutorial I'm following](http://javabrains.koushik.org/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Setting-Up) is telling me that the correct URL to be using here is `http://localhost:8080/messenger/`.

Comment: Are you using `http://localhost:port/your-project/webapi/myresource`?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/messenger/ when attempting to run it from the project folder itself via Right-Click -> Run As -> Run on Server (Tomcat 7).  It says that /messenger/ is the missing resource. I also attempted to do the same thing on MyResource.java which is http://localhost:8080/messenger/WEB-INF/classes/org/myName/mySite/messenger/MyResource.java, and returns a blank under missing resource.

Comment: If your project is named `messenger`, have you tried `http://localhost:port/messenger/webapi/myresource`

Comment: I tried `http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource/` and got the same 404 result (also `http://localhost:port/messenger/webapi/myresource` verbatim) . Apologies for my noobish-ness I am new to everything mentioned except Java and Eclipse.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30020830/2587435) how you created the project?

Comment: Yes that is close to how I created the project. I was using `jersey-quickstart-webapp` 2.17 because 2.16 was giving me errors about referencing nonexisting libraries.

Comment: Please see below. Try to do that. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77675/discussion-between-dumpcats-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 1):

### This is not an answer <s>(will be deleted)</s>

**Edit:** Turned into community wiki. It's not a solution.

Try and add this jetty plugin to the app. Inside the `<build><plugins>` in the `pom.xml` file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.6.v20141205</version>
</plugin>
```

Then Right click on project, Maven -> Build; in the dialog on the goals type `jetty:run` and try to run the build. This should start an embedded jetty server. Once the console says "Jetty Server started", you should be able to access `http://localhost:8080/webapi/myresource`. Just want to see if it is a problem with the app.

Comment: I was able to access my Java file! I'll have to look into why this works, but at least this multiple hour long headache has closure.

Comment: Maybe a problem with Tomcat configuration in Eclipse. It's been a while since I ran a Maven webapp on Eclipse, so I'm not sure what the problem is. But at least you know it's not a problem with the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Fast Temporary solution:**

Change **webapi** to **webresources** in the url: http://localhost:8080/webapi/myresource

**Permanent solution:**

Change the file web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
```