# create portable jar file from java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, executable-jar

I used **javabuilder.jar** and **CommodityWeigth.jar** (which is my own jar file) in my java project. I want to create executable jar file from that project and use *@joost* answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse). But I get warnings:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type Classpath entry C:/Users/sahar/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/ahp/libs/commodityWeight.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.    ahp     P/ahp   Classpath Dependency Validator Message
Description Resource Path Location Type Classpath entry E:/Matlab/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.    ahp     P/ahp   Classpath Dependency Validator Message
```

and Because of these warnings, the jar file will not run correctly .

also when i open created jar file with WinRAR, I can see javabuilder and CommodityWeigth jars.

Comment: The answer you linked to might already contain the answer to you as well  -- have you tried '/Extract/ required libraries into generated JAR' instead of '/Package/ required libraries into generated JAR'?

Comment: I used both "Extract required libraries ..." and "Package required libraries ..." . But none of them resolved my problem.

Comment: How about trying Eclipse [quickfix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9248287/5583149) for selecting the libraries under discussion as export/publish dependencies then?

Comment: @unserializable **quickfix** solve my problem. thanks.